# How to use conditions inside Email template in SugarCRM

Tags: php, sugarcrm, email-templates

How I can use if/else conditions inside the email template in SugarCRM?
I am trying use conditions equal pdf template and smarty template but I have no success.

No success

```
<?php if ({::past::Opportunities::name::} != {::future::Opportunities::name::}){ ?>
```

No success

```
{if {::past::Opportunities::name::} neq {::future::Opportunities::name::}}
```

no success

```
<!-- {if {::past::Opportunities::name::} neq {::future::Opportunities::name::}} -->
```

Any success (?)

```
??????
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems, that [official SugarCRM docs](http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/01_Sugar_Editions/04_Sugar_Professional/Sugar_Professional_7.2/Application_Guide/23_Emails/#Creating_Email_Templates) don't provide any information about using if/else conditions in email templates. I didn't believed them, so i dug into [SugarCRM](https://github.com/sugarcrm/sugarcrm_dev) code.

**Research:**

Sending e-mail is done in [EmailMan class](https://github.com/sugarcrm/sugarcrm_dev/blob/3f8126ba8c4d4f60b170199f68e2ee86dc8dd40c/modules/EmailMan/EmailMan.php) in method sendEmail:

```
$template_data = $this->current_emailtemplate
                    ->parse_email_template(
                    array(
                        'subject' => $this->current_emailtemplate->subject,
                        'body_html' => $this->current_emailtemplate->body_html,
                        'body' => $this->current_emailtemplate->body,
                    )
                    , $focus_name, $module
                    , $macro_nv);
```

It uses parse_email_template method from [class EmailTemplate](https://github.com/sugarcrm/sugarcrm_dev/blob/3f8126ba8c4d4f60b170199f68e2ee86dc8dd40c/modules/EmailTemplates/EmailTemplate.php). It's not so well-written, as i was thinking. And it's only providing basic variable replacing. Let's look at it a little closer:

```
function parse_email_template($template_text_array, $focus_name, $focus, &$macro_nv)
    {
        [...] //variable initiation
        //preparing prefixes to search for variables (all variables are in "$some_name" format
        $pattern_prefix = '$' . strtolower($beanList[$focus_name]) . '_';
        $pattern_prefix_length = strlen($pattern_prefix);
        $pattern = '/\\' . $pattern_prefix . '[A-Za-z_0-9]*/';


        foreach ($template_text_array as $key => $template_text) {
            [...] //searching for variables matching $pattern and replacing them with proper values

            $return_array[$key] = $template_text;
        }

        return $return_array;
    }
```

**Conclusion:**

What i can say more - SugarCRM at this point doesn't provide any conditions nor smarty or other template engine. You can try to modify their code to implement it, but i wouldn't recommend that as it is a litlle [spaghetti](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code) ;)

Answer (score 1):

handlebarsjs may help?
http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html

```
{{#if yourcondition}} action {{else}} action{{/if}}
```

Comment: In monday I will try your solution :)

Comment: @mg33dev - i dug up in code, i'm afraid that's not handlebars either. It's some "let's-preg-match-everything" attempt :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this and see how you go:

```
{if $fieldname!="value"}sometext {$fieldname} {/if}
```